# how to change ether to flat currency

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, exchanges

I would like to know how can i exchange my ether in my MEW wallet for flat currencies like USD, INR etc. It would be highly appreciable if anyone can guide me with this.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: But i already have ether, i want to change it to flat currency

Comment: Read the answers there please, its more or less the same.

Comment: Use any exchange to convert your ethers to fiat.

Comment: can you brief or suggest exchanges @PrashantPrabhakarSingh thanks

Comment: Have  a look https://inc42.com/features/cryptocurrency-exchanges-ethereum-bitcoin-india/. You can choose Koinex for exchanging your ether with inr.